# PHP Regular Expressions (REGEX) Multipart MIME (NOT-EMAIL)

Tags: php, regex, mime, boundary

I'm trying to do a "preg match all" on the response below to get all the binary data. I've tried just about everything imaginable and for the life of me, can't get anything.

I was hoping it'd be as simple as doing something like this:

```
preg_match_all("#\n\n(.*)\n--$boundary#",$body,$matches);
```

But I can't get anything. I've tried other stuff too. \r \n | i s m U - I just can't get it for some reason.

Here is a pseudo response not including the headers:

```
--boundary
content-type:image/jpeg

<binary data>
--boundary
content-type:image/jpeg

<binary data>
--boundary
content-type:image/jpeg

<binary data>
--boundary
```

unfortunately the binary data isn't enclosed with < & > it's just raw data with special characters over the course of multiple lines...

also: i think the problem lies within the actual binary data that is being displayed because when i run a preg match all on the info above it works just fine but when i try it on the actual data that has all the binary data crap in it, it doesn't work.

Comment: Also could you please post your sample here instead of the url. Someone else might stumble upon your question in the future when the content of this link has long been altered.

Comment: I tried the regex on the data you provide and it worked. Try echoing out the variable $boundary to check its what you expect.

Comment: There are no errors in my script like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could parse with explode() this should be much faster, it's not too complex, and it gives you the header info if you want it:

```
<?php

$body = file_get_contents('output.txt');
$boundary = '__NEXT_PART_gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p__';
$parts = explode("--$boundary", $body);
array_shift($parts); # delete up to the first boundary
array_pop($parts); # delete after the last boundary

$binaries = array();
foreach($parts as $part) {
    list($header, $binary) = explode("\n\n", $part, 2);
    $binaries[] = $binary;
}    

print_r($binaries);
```

Answer (score 2):

`\n` is platform dependent. Presumably your data is a http-request or an email? In this case, line breaks will be `\r\n`, so you need to test for that instead

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks for the tip. So \r\n is pretty much universal?

Comment: No, but it's standard for most web-based protocols (http and mail).

Answer (score 1):

You're expression seems to work fine for me on the data you provided. I pulled down your output.php, and renamed it output.txt, then ran this script:

```
<?php

$body = file_get_contents('output.txt');
$boundary = '__NEXT_PART_gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p__';
preg_match_all("#\n\n(.*)\n--$boundary#",$body,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Seems to have worked fine, ie it printed this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 

    [body] => 
--__NEXT_PART_gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p__
            [1] => 

ÿ( RAW IMAGE DATA CONTINUES OVER MULTIPLE LINES starts with "ÿ" ends with "ÿÙ" )ÿÙ
--__NEXT_PART_gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p__
            [2] => 

ÿ( RAW IMAGE DATA CONTINUES OVER MULTIPLE LINES starts with "ÿ" ends with "ÿÙ" )ÿÙ
--__NEXT_PART_gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p__
            [3] => 

ÿ( RAW IMAGE DATA CONTINUES OVER MULTIPLE LINES starts with "ÿ" ends with "ÿÙ" )ÿÙ
--__NEXT_PART_gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p__
            [4] => 

ÿ( RAW IMAGE DATA CONTINUES OVER MULTIPLE LINES starts with "ÿ" ends with "ÿÙ" )ÿÙ
--__NEXT_PART_gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p__
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>     [body] => 
            [1] => ÿ( RAW IMAGE DATA CONTINUES OVER MULTIPLE LINES starts with "ÿ" ends with "ÿÙ" )ÿÙ
            [2] => ÿ( RAW IMAGE DATA CONTINUES OVER MULTIPLE LINES starts with "ÿ" ends with "ÿÙ" )ÿÙ
            [3] => ÿ( RAW IMAGE DATA CONTINUES OVER MULTIPLE LINES starts with "ÿ" ends with "ÿÙ" )ÿÙ
            [4] => ÿ( RAW IMAGE DATA CONTINUES OVER MULTIPLE LINES starts with "ÿ" ends with "ÿÙ" )ÿÙ
        )

)
```

Looks like the $matches[1] contains the list of binary data you're after.

Comment: im still getting two empty arrays :(

Comment: oh shit... i think i found out what's causing the problem..

i get nothing when i run this script locally on my windows xp pc using wamp but when i run it on my linux server it works just fine. any ideas?

Comment: oh and, you were only supposed to run the preg match on the stuff that is in the [body]=>array // but other than that i guess it works just fine, but not on windows... hmm

Comment: ahh windows...

Try passing FILE_BINARY as the 2nd parameter to file_get_contents()

Comment: you might also try a double backslash before your ns (like \\n) so it's expanded by preg instead of php string constants.

Comment: well i'm not file_get(ing)_conents on it.. I'm getting it via a string and i'm developing on windows but i need it to work in both windows and linux

and i dont quite understand the what you mean in your second comment

Comment: In my second comment, I meant try this: preg_match_all("#\\n\\n(.*)\\n--$boundary#",$body,$matches); (that is, \\n instead of \n. I don't have access to a windows machine to test on, but I just thought it'd be worth a shot.

Comment: I think you should upload the output.txt file and test with that on your windows machine. I think that would would give a hint as to where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer regarding your regular expressions, but did you have a look at [Zend_Mime](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mime.html)?

Comment: yeah, i have in the past, that zend stuff is foreign to me but thanks for the tip.

Comment: Well if you don't like to learn how to use the Zend Framework you could also have a look at the Zend_Mime_Decode class. I suppose the splitMime function could be very helpful for you. Here's the link: http://framework.zend.com/code/browse/~raw,r=9280/Zend_Framework/trunk/library/Zend/Mime/Decode.php

Comment: that class is using a method similar to the one i have already made. i just want to see if i can parse the <binary data> with one preg_match_all statement.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well I'm not all that familiar with PHP regular expressions...

Considering what you are trying to do, the dot-matches-newline s switch should work.  Using this regular expression seemed to work on my end:

```
/<binary data>\r\n(.*?)\r\n--simple boundary/s
```

The *? should be non-greedy, and so it will gobble only so much as to match the very first --simple boundary text string it sees.

Your line endings may differ from mine (I'm on a Windows machine), so you may have to fire up a hex editor to see exactly what should be matched before and after the `<binary data>` content.

Comment: thanks for the tip, i'll try that.

after seeing that JasonWoof was able to get it to work I narrowed my issue down to the OS the script is being ran on opposed to the regex itself that works just fine on a linux box.

Comment: glad to hear that you've narrowed it down